# Incompatible type int[] cannot be converted to int error

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to bring in grade values and name values from a .dat file called in a separate runner program. The class in this other java file was begun for us, and we had to "instantiate both arrays..." and "use a for-loop..."

I'm getting an error

```
Incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int" error for "grades[i]=g;" and the corresponding String error for "names[i]=n;
```

Thoughts?

```
public GradeBook(int[] g, String[] n, int num)
{
    // **instantiate both arrays with 'num' objects
            String []names=new String[num];
            int[] grades=new int[num];
    //**use a for-loop to assign each name and grade with the incoming values
            for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
            {
                names[i]=n;
                grades[i]=g;
            }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full code for the class.  I don't see the point of iterating at all here, just assign the incoming arrays and be done with it.

Comment: maybe you mean `             names[i]=n[i];
                grades[i]=g[i];`  although https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int) would be better

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `num` might be a different value to `n.length`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Still a one line operation: `String[] names = Arrays.copyOf(n, num);`

Comment: @shmosel indeed

Comment: @shmosel My gut feeling is that he doesn't need to use array copy here, maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your actual code should look something like this:

```
public class GradeBook {
    private String[] names;
    private int[] grades;

    public GradeBook(int[] g, String[] n) {
        names = n;
        grades = g;
    }
}
```

Just assign the incoming grades and names in your constructor.  You don't need to worry about length of the incoming array, because the caller already had to deal with this, perhaps while reading in the `.dat` file.  And iterating also isn't necessary here.

If you really need to make copies of the array passed as input to your constructor, then you can use `System.arraycopy()` for that:

```
public class GradeBook {
    private String[] names;
    private int[] grades;

    public GradeBook(int[] g, String[] n) {
        names = new String[n.length];
        grades = new int[g.length];
        System.arraycopy(n, 0, names, 0, n.length);
        System.arraycopy(g, 0, grades, 0, g.length);
    }
```

Note that you would only need to make a copy if the code calling the constructor planned on also modifying the array later on.

Comment: This won't make a copy, it will just assign the reference ... not sure if the OP want's a copy or not, but I'd worth point it out - IMHO ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I know this.  I assumed that the code calling the constructor read in the `.dat` file and passed it in, without having the further need to use that array.

Comment: I'm not worried about you knowing, I'm worried about the OP knowing, it's difficult to be 100% sure, but based on their code they "might" want to make another copy ... or not, it might be helpful to the OP to point the differences in this case so they have a better idea of what's going, just saying ;) - if you don't feel it's required, then don't ;)